# Pedals feel like they are too far back

Tags: pedals

I bought a cheap bike to ride around the driveway/neighborhood with my kids.  It feels like the pedals are right underneath my butt rather than just in front.  Makes for not so comfortable position.  Is there a reason for this?  Anything that can be done about it?

Comment: The seat is too far forward.

Comment: And yes, ladies and gents, DRH is right. As usual.

Answer (score 8):

Well, there are a ton of adjustments you can make, but sometimes a bike just won't fit someone. You may want to look up "[bike fit](http://www.peterwhitecycles.com/fitting.htm)", though this is something you probably should have done before you bought the bike.

You can:

- Move the saddle backwards
- Move the saddle up/down
- Change the angle of the saddle
- Change the stem height
- Change the stem (to get a different length/angle)
- Re-angle the handlebars

I'd start with moving around the saddle, since doing anything other than re-angling the bars may not be an option.

The saddle height is adjusted by a bolt or quick release lever where the seatpost goes into the frame. The rest of the adjustments are normally controlled by an allen key on the bottom of the saddle, where it is clamped into the seatpost. You can see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycA1tpSWeqA) for example.